# How to count inside jQuery.each where specific value is 1

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to count Array where value=1 inside jQuery.each?

This is my Array: `result[index].isopen`

This is my Code:

```
jQuery.each(result, function(index, item) {

console.log(result[index].isopen);  

)};
```

This is the console.log:

```
0
1
1
```

How to create a var that counts the results where `result[index].isopen` = 1?
In this case it will be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable before the `jQuery.each` line and increment it:

```
var openCount = 0;

jQuery.each(result, function(index, item) {
    if (item.isopen) {
        openCount++;
    }
});

console.log(openCount);
```

You also need to fix your closing line of the each from `)};` to `});`

You can also just do this with vanilla JS using the `filter` function to filter the items and then check the length of the filtered array:

```
var openResults = results.filter(function (item) {
    return item.isopen;
});

console.log(openResults.length)
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is working and i leaned how to solve this problem/question. Best regards!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable before the loop and increment inside the loop.

```
var count = 0;
jQuery.each(result, function(index, item) {

   if (item.isopen) {
      count++;
   }

});

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is working and i leaned how to solve this problem/question. Best regards!!!